# Material UI Popover - how to open it without Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Because of an external library I have to use and I cannot avoid, a re-render of a Component I have is causing this error message:

```
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

I know this is caused because I'm using hooks inside my component. See my component content:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Popover from '@material-ui/core/Popover';

import ImageCell from 'App/components/DatabaseTable/Utils/ImageCell';

const Image = ({ defaultValueRow, valueRow }) => {
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
const id = `popover-${defaultValueRow[valueRow]}`;

const handlePopoverOpen = (event) => setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);

const handlePopoverClose = () => setAnchorEl(null);

return (
 <>
   <Box
     aria-haspopup={'true'}
     aria-owns={anchorEl ? id : undefined}
     onMouseEnter={handlePopoverOpen}
     onMouseLeave={handlePopoverClose}
   >
     <ImageCell src={valueRow[defaultValueRow]} />
   </Box>
   <Popover
     id={id}
     style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
     PaperProps={{
       style: { padding: '8px' },
     }}
     open={anchorEl}
     anchorEl={anchorEl}
     anchorOrigin={{
       vertical: 'top',
       horizontal: 'center',
     }}
     transformOrigin={{
       vertical: 'bottom',
       horizontal: 'center',
     }}
   >
     <ImageCell
       style={{ maxWidth: '125rem', maxHeight: '15rem' }}
       src={valueRow[defaultValueRow]}
     />
   </Popover>
  </>
  );
 };

 export default Image;
```

As I cannot avoid using this external library, I was wondering:
**Is there any way to manage anchorEl to not be using the useState hook?**

Comment: are you sure that the problem is with this component? From the look of it it should not give you the specified error.

Comment: I'm sure this Component is not the problem, but for now I cannot avoid the Component that produces it... So I was wondering if I could avoid the hooks for now...

Comment: The only way the useState hook in this component could be causing that message is if this `Image` component is called conditionally as a function in another component (which then presumably renders what gets returned from calling `Image()`) rather than being rendered as an element. Is that what is happening? It is difficult to recommend a course of action without seeing the context of how this component gets used.

Comment: Hummm could be... Gonna see if I can touch the other Component and I might report a bug for it... Because this one is fine... Thanks for the advice @RyanCogswell

Comment: @RyanCogswell so at the end you were completely right. I could go into the external code, copy it and reproduce it locally, and based on your answer I could find the problem. I just changed the component to be called as a React Component, not as a function.
Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept it?